# Sina Weibo API callback problem

Tags: social-networking, weibo, sinaweibo

Has anyone here been able to connect to the Sina Weibo API?
I hit a brick wall when it comes to the callback URL.
I seems it will only allow a root folder as URL
so www.example.com works but www.example.com/sina doesn't

anyone knows a work around?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone has the same problem, you have probably entered the URL under the "security" heading rather than the Authorization settings heading (at the top) on the developer settings page). The URL it is asking for in the security section is a base url with which the application can be used (hence why it only takes .com domains) whereas the one above can take any format that you want your callback url to be.

Hope that helps, the settings page in question is here:
http://open.weibo.com/apps/yourappid/info/advanced (replacing the your app id as appropriate)

Comment: Thanks buddy..realy helped me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Sina OAuth callback page? Your callback URL should be URL encoded according to the API document. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: the URL is encoded, i even tried "http://www.example.com/test" and it says it is in an illegal format. but "http://www.example.com" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I m using PHP libweibo http://code.google.com/p/libweibo/
i m succesfully implement that script demo.
i m facing that problem too.

if youare using oauth2.0,
you need to make sure that your callback FILE exactly same as callback URL in weibo apps page.